# About deeplink url length

Tags: json, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

Is tehere any size limit for deeplink url for using with parameters? For example

application://saveUser?data={longJsonString}

If I pass very long json string to the deeplink data param, will it occure an error?

Comment: Did you get any answer of this question? I also have this question.